# How to make a custom model for the default Module in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Anyone know how to change the default Module in Zend Framework 2? I am using the Skeleton Application as the home page but I want to make another module that I have the default home page. 
I tried two things

I removed the "Skeleton Application" from the application.config.php file this is what it looked like

```
return array(
'modules' => array(
    'Application',
    'Helloworld'
),
'module_listener_options' => array(
    'config_glob_paths'    => array(
        'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
    ),
    'module_paths' => array(
        './module',
        './vendor',
    ),
  ),
);
```

this is what it looks like now

```
    return array(
'modules' => array(
    'Helloworld'
),
'module_listener_options' => array(
    'config_glob_paths'    => array(
        'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
    ),
    'module_paths' => array(
        './module',
        './vendor',
     ),
   ),
);
```

if you can't tell I removed the 'Application' from the module 
then I changed my module.config.php file for the Helloworld module 
here's what it used to look like

```
return array(
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'sayhello' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/sayhello',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Helloworld\Controller\Index',
                    'action' => 'index',
                )
            )
        )
    )
),
'controllers' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Helloworld\Controller\Index' => 'Helloworld\Controller\IndexControllerFactory'
    )
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'greetingService' => 'Helloworld\Service\GreetingService'
     )
   )
);
```

this is what it looks like now

```
return array(
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'sayhello' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Helloworld\Controller\Index',
                    'action' => 'index',
                )
            )
        )
    )
),
'controllers' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Helloworld\Controller\Index' => 'Helloworld\Controller\IndexControllerFactory'
    )
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'greetingService' => 'Helloworld\Service\GreetingService'
      )
   )
);
```

the change was made to the 'router' array in the options=>route I changed the value to just '/'

but it throws a 5000 error 
can anyone elaborate on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: now i remember why i switched to Symfony...

Comment: did you renamed the folder `Application` to `Helloworld` in `src` folder ? it must solve your routing issue

Comment: thank you for replies. I guess I just didn't understand how the template defaults worked they basically cascade. Which is why I got away without creating layouts in my hello world and as long as the "Skeleton Application" was in there mine also worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I saw the problem with my application. The routing is actually correct the problem was that I was missing a layout.phtml file I needed to specify all this in the module configuration. I need to add the following to my module.config.php

```
    'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'valaree/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/valaree/index/index.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set your project home page by setting url in module.config.php of application module 
(myproject/module/application/config/module.config.php) in home route. For Example, if you want to use Index Action of Index Controller of Default Module as your home page you need to change the home route in above mentioned file. i.e

```
     'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Default\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

Please make sure you define your new module in (myproject/config/application.config.php) before using above code. Please let me know if you required any further help. Thanks..:)